# Mysql 5.6 tmpdir change deletes some users

Tags: mysql, replication

We have a Percona-mysql 5.6 setup with one master and one replica.
After trying to do a big `ALTER TABLE` on it, it failed because the tmpdir was inside of the memory and therefore wasn't big enough.

Changing the tmpdir on the slaves did not bring any problems but changing it on the master led to some users from mysql.user being deleted.
We have reproduced this a second time on our staging setup.

We changed the tmpdir through shutting down MySQL after setting it to `read_only` (so no operation is dangling there) and then changing the variable in `my.cnf`.

Did anyone encounter something similar or could suggest a way to prevent this? We have no clue how a tmpdir change could affect the users table on the instance.